# Failed getStringExtra Kotlin mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I want to move from one `Activity` which displays a `RecyclerView` to another `Activity` (detail). But when I added data transmission via `Intent`, the data always failed to be taken in the `Activity` detail.

This is the error:
[image]

My `MainDetail`:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MainDetailModel
    var idAnime: String = "34134"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_detail)
        idAnime = intent.getStringExtra("idAnime")
        println("idanime $idAnime")
        setupFragment()
        setupViewModel()
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```
class MainViewModel(context: Application, private val appRepository: AppRepository, private val contexts: Context) : AndroidViewModel(context), MainItemClickAction {
    override fun onItemClicked(detailModel: DetailModel) {
        var intent = Intent(contexts, MainDetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("idAnime",detailModel.mal_id )
        contexts.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a place in the code when you start `MainDetailActivity` without adding the stringExtra `idAnime`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your field "detailModel.mal_id" mal_id in that case is string, because you're requesting string in details activity. If it's string check also if this "mal_id" is null. Other issues from code you provided can't be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Check your value **idAnime**, it exists or not, I think is better check all value is empty or not before putting into listView or another view.